# Syncfusion Vue accessing elements

Tags: vue.js, syncfusion

I'm using some syncfusion Vue controls, sometimes the examples on the documentation accesses controls using the $refs and some examples they use raw JavaScript such as getelementbyid. Sometimes if you try to use the $refs then you end up with properties of that control being null or undefined which forces you to use the native JavaScript to access the control. My question is does this go against the principles of Vue as it looks like I'm being forced to access the dom directly, which I've read carefully cause issues with Vue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify the following details in which case you were unable to access the property using $refs in Vue.

- Vue Component and Property
- Vue Environment